# Обмен данных в формах

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть Form1 и Form2.
В Form1 есть TextBox который постоянно меняется.
В Form2 есть Label в который должна помещаться информация из TextBox.
Как это сделать более правильно?

Comment: Да, забыл сказать, WinForm

Comment: как у вас связаны `Form1` и `Form2`?

Comment: Никак, они обе открыты в одном проекте в одном namespace

Comment: Добавьте код в ваш вопрос

Answer (score -5):

```
Form1.TextBox.text = Form2.Label.text;
```

Так мб?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Для такого варианта вам придётся объявить контролы форм как public. А это грубо говоря не очень хорошо.